# Git on command line behaving very strangely

Tags: git, command-line, gitlab

So, I haven't used gitlab in a while but have to again for work. Yesterday I trialed cloning an old project, pulling a specific branch and then pushing again - was working fine.

So, today I try to do the same again but with things I want to work on now. I can clone fine - no issues there, but if I try to switch onto a specific branch, which definitely exists, I'm getting

> error: pathspec 'BRANCHNAME' did not match any file(s) known to git

So, I used git remote update to see if that would help and, despite having cloned from the repo just a couple of minutes ago I'm now getting

> Fetching origin fatal: 'git@gitlab.work/folder/repo.git' does
> not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote
> repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists. error: Could not fetch origin

Could it be something to do with the fact I use HTTPS to clone? I had to input my account password yesterday in a popup, which isn't happening today. It's all I can think of that's different.

Comment: Please show the result of `git branch -av`...

Comment: anecdotally, I've always had more success with ssh keys and seen weird errors with peoples' https clones

Comment: @Christoph there is no result at all. when I hit enter about 20 seconds pass with no result, and then it reverts to ready for a command

Comment: Strange... What does `git status` say?

Comment: The "could not read from remote repository" error can mean anything from "doesn't exist" to "network is down at this moment, try again in a minute" to "everything's fine *except* that the remote machine no longer likes you for some reason". In this case the last seems the most likely. The admins at the remote machine are the ones to ask why their machine suddenly hates you (apparently temporarily).

Comment: Entirely unhelpfully I have no idea why this started working again when I came back to work the next day, but it did.